# Ошибка при переносе данных из MSSQL в MySQL с использованием MySQL Workbench. Что делать?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

При миграции базы из `MSSQL` в `MySQL` возникает ошибка:

```
Default value newid() is not supported
```

Пытался гуглить, там сказано про `UUID` вместо `NEWID()`, но я ничего не понял. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, понять что надо сделать чтобы скопировать данные?

Comment: Выгрузить отдельно скрипт создания таблицы, откорректировать в синтаксис MySQL, создать таблицу, потом скопировать в неё данные.

Comment: Ткни в миску, пожалуйста! Как это сделать? Отдельно в файл выгрузить составление таблиц? Где это?

Comment: Ну или https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-wizard-schemata.html, или запустить SSMS.